# Не могу подключиться к локальной сети Windows через Wi-Fi Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

Установлена на ноутбуке Ubuntu 21.04, подключаюсь к сети по Wi-Fi - интернет работает, но ни как не могу настроить, что бы можно было видеть остальные компьютеры, которые есть в сети. При этом выполнив следующую команду видно, что отклик от компьютеров в сети есть.

```
$ echo 192.168.0.{1..254}|xargs -n1 -P0 ping -c1|grep "bytes from"
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=16.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=17.2 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.66: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=7.41 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.717 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.109: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.025 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.102: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=9.62 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.118: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1.20 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.101: icmp_seq=1 ttl=100 time=11.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.111: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=9.24 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.146: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=6.58 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.151: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=13.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.159: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=10.9 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.161: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=10.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.160: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=13.6 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.189: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=13.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.192: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=18.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.190: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=20.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.205: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=14.2 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.250: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=8.21 ms
```

При попытке подключиться через smb://..... не подключается, а зависает процесс.
В интернете везде пишут как настраивать проводное подключение, аналогично настраиваю Wi-Fi, не работает, поэтому делаю вывод, что не все так просто.

Comment: «При попытке подключиться через smb://...» по имени ПК или по IP?

Comment: Пробовал и по IP и по им1ени компьютера. При чем в какой-то момент компьютеры появились, все заработало, но потом все опять сломалось, сделал чистую установку и ничего не работает.